# deployment fails with juju and Maas

Tags: lubuntu, juju, maas, openstack, continuous-deployment

I am trying to bootstrap a VM machine in order to deploy Openstack cloud and it hangs as below:

```
maasadmin@FGSUSSUMAAS01:~$ juju bootstrap stagingmaas
Creating Juju controller "stagingmaas" on stagingmaas
Looking for packaged Juju agent version 2.2.6 for amd64
Launching controller instance(s) on stagingmaas...
- qrdf8y (arch=amd64 mem=10G cores=10)
Fetching Juju GUI 2.10.2
Waiting for address
Attempting to connect to 10.x.0.10:22  <<<<<<<<<<<

maasadmin@FGSUSSUMAAS01:~/openstack-stg$ juju --version
2.2.6-xenial-amd64
```

Is there any way to fix this out?

Also please note if I use below details in `bootstrap.config` file, bootstrap succeeds. 10.139.0.50 is the private IP of maas server.

```
default-series: xenial
no-proxy: localhost
http-proxy: http://10.x.0.50:8000 
https-proxy: http://10.x.0.50:8000
ftp-proxy: http://10.x.0.50:8000
```

If I use public IP of maas server in config file, bootstrap fails.

As you see 10.x.0.50 is the private IP of maas server and Openstack deployment fails with:

```
Machine  State    DNS          Inst id  Series  AZ       Message
0        down     10.x.0.17  4rc3n3   xenial  default  Failed deployment: Power state queried: on
0/lxd/0  pending               pending  xenial
0/lxd/1  pending               pending  xenial
0/lxd/2  pending               pending  xenial
0/lxd/3  pending               pending  xenial
0/lxd/4  pending               pending  xenial
1        down     10.x.0.18  gst3at   xenial  default  Failed deployment: Power state queried: on
1/lxd/0  pending               pending  xenial
1/lxd/1  pending               pending  xenial
1/lxd/2  pending               pending  xenial
1/lxd/3  pending               pending  xenial
2        down     10.x.0.19  s8pct4   xenial  default  Failed deployment: Power state queried: on
3        down     10.x.0.20  7nrsab   xenial  default  Failed deployment: Power state queried: on
4        down     10.x.0.21  7pqsdy   xenial  default  Failed deployment: Power state queried: on
```

Please see the attachment also.

So in order to get deployment going I need the bootstrap issue to get resolved.